# How can fix this code? button on click will give 1 point & another that remove 1

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, points

I have used

```
<button onclick="addPoint()>
```

```
var p = document.getElementById("p");
var total = 0;


function addPoint() {
    total++
}

function minusPoint() {
    total--;
}

p.innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: my html <button class="button" onclick="addPoint()">add a point</button>
<button class="button" onclick="minusPoint()">remove a point</button>
<p id="p">Points:</p>

Comment: `p.innerHTML = total;` is not going to magically run when total is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update element value `p.innerHTML = total;` inside the click handler as below

```js
var p = document.getElementById("p"); var total = 0;
function addPoint() {
    total++;
    p.innerHTML = total;
}

function minusPoint() {
    total--;
    p.innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="addPoint()">add a point</button> <button class="button" onclick="minusPoint()">remove a point</button> <p id="p">Points:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML to update the total every time the buttons are clicked.

```
var p = document.getElementById("p"); 
var total = 0;
function addPoint() {
    total++;
    p.innerHTML = total;
}

function minusPoint() {
    total--;
    p.innerHTML = total;
}
```